# About the use and the output of outer()

Tags: arrays, r, function

Please, run the following reproducible code:

```
require(compiler)

a <- 1:80
n <- 1:140

fn <- cmpfun(function(a, n)
{
  K <- ceiling(runif(n, min = 1, max = 80))
  p <- length(K[K >= min(80, a + 5)]) / n
  return(p)
})
```

It is sure the `fn()` function returns a number smaller than `1`, due to the fact that it should return the frequency of the random numbers from `K` which are greater than `a + 5`; this can be verified with random integer inputs in `fn()`:

```
for(i in seq(8, 80, 8))
{
  for(j in seq(14, 140, 14))
  {
    print(fn(i,j))
  }
}
```

Now I would like to get the cross-function of `fn()` applied to `a` and `n` arrays, and I thought `outer()` was the best solution:

> The outer product of the arrays `X` and `Y` is the array `A` with dimension `c(dim(X), dim(Y))` where element `A[c(arrayindex.x, arrayindex.y)] = FUN(X[arrayindex.x], Y[arrayindex.y], ...)`.

I would expect to get output from `0` to `1` but

```
persp(x = a, y = n, z = outer(X = a, Y = n, FUN = fn), 
      ticktype = 'detailed', phi = 30, theta = 120)
```

does return this output, instead:

[image]

What I am missing in the use of `outer()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length(K[K >= min(80, a + 5)])` isn't what you think it is. `outer` needs a function, which is vectorized in both parameters. Your function is vectorized by chance, but not in the way you want.

Look at this:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1:5
x <- runif(n, min = 1, max = 80)
#[1] 73.26968 75.02896 23.60502 66.60536 51.69790
x/n
#[1] 73.269677 37.514479  7.868341 16.651341 10.339579
```

Comment: But isn't `n` supposed to be a single number in my function? It is not an array, is it? Then it should make the ratio of `K` (`x` in your example) to a single number, not to an array...

Comment: You assume that n is a length one vector. The base functions you are using don't assume this.

Answer (score 1):

As @Roland said, the function you need to input to `outer` need to be vectorized first. One way of doing this:

```
fn_vec <- Vectorize(fn)
outer(a,n,fn_vec)
```